# PowerShell: break nested loops

Tags: loops, powershell, break

There should be a `break` command in PowerShell that can exit nested loops by assigning a label. Just it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
$timestampServers = @(
    "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll",
    "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode",
    "http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll",
    "http://www.startssl.com/timestamp"
)

:outer for ($retry = 2; $retry -gt 0; $retry--)
{
    Write-Host retry $retry
    foreach ($timestampServer in $timestampServers)
    {
        Write-Host timestampServer $timestampServer
        & $signtoolBin sign /f $keyFile /p "$password" /t $timestampServer $file
        if ($?)
        {
            Write-Host OK
            break :outer
        }
    }
}
if ($retry -eq 0)
{
    WaitError "Digitally signing failed"
    exit 1
}
```

It prints the following:

```
retry 2
timestampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: C:\myfile.dll
OK
retry 1
timestampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: C:\myfile.dll
OK

ERROR: Digitally signing failed
```

What have I done wrong?

Can I have goto and labels, please?

Using Windows 7 and I guess PS 2.0. This script is supposed to run on PS 2 at least.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You do not add the colon when using `break` with a loop label.  This line:

```powershell
break :outer
```

should be written like this:

```powershell
break outer
```

For a further demonstration, consider this simple script:

```powershell
:loop while ($true)
{
    while ($true)
    {
        break :loop
    }
}
```

When executed, it will run forever without breaking.  This script however:

```powershell
:loop while ($true)
{
    while ($true)
    {
        break loop
    }
}
```

exits as it should because I changed `break :loop` to `break loop`.

Comment: Technet docs at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx show the colon in the break statement, but I tested this as well and found the same as iCodez: with the colon it ignored the label (just broke from the inner loop), without the colon it would break from the labeled loop.

Comment: @iCodez no, actually you are right... I thought it was working but it is not.

Comment: Thank you. I must have overlooked that. You should never rely on arbitrary websites to learn a programming language. But with PowerShell this seems necessary.

Comment: the Doc must have been fixed, there is no colon there now. Nor when I change [Doc version to PS 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Break?view=powershell-3.0), or use `Get-Help about_break` in PS 5.1 console. But it still is on [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/08/powershell-looping-advanced-break/)

Comment: thanks for the demonstration. It worked fine for me

Comment: Regarding faulty documentation at [about_Break](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx) (redirects to current), question was asked Jun 4 '14 but [Hey, Scripting Guy!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/08/powershell-looping-advanced-break/) article dated May 8 '14 states "The colon is left out of the Help examples that illustrate breaking to a label. ... the colon is required." suggesting the help doc did not have a : at time question posted. BTW, this article purports that "break label" can GOTO a labelled loop but the example output disproves this->

Comment: -> also, [Archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140501213818/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx) from 1 May '14 has no : in the break parameter. Further, oldest capture (captured 23 Jan '13 but dated 9 Aug '12) has no : (PS V3). Even PS V2.0 help, obtained via "help about_break" on clean installed Win7 from DVD (about_Break.help.txt 21/11/2010 11:38AM), has no : on the break parameter in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

So, I changed the code a bit to make it clear

```
$timestampServers = @(
    "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll",
    "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode",
    "http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll",
    "http://www.startssl.com/timestamp"
)


:outer for ($retry = 2; $retry -gt 0; $retry--)
{
    Write-Host retry $retry
    foreach ($timestampServer in $timestampServers)
    {
        Write-Host timestampServer $timestampServer
        #& $signtoolBin sign /f $keyFile /p "$password" /t $timestampServer $file

        if ($true)
        {

            break :outer
            Write-Host OK
        }
    }
}
if ($retry -eq 0)
{
    Write-Error "Digitally signing failed"  ## you have a typo there
    exit 1
}
```

This produces the following:

```
retry 2
timestampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
retry 1
timestampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
C:\temp\t.ps1 : Digitally signing failed
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,t.ps1
```

So, skips Write-Host OK, but also seems to continue to loop. In other words, it acts like 'Continue' statement.

Changed it like the folks mentioned to remove ':', although PowerShell documentation does not exclude it:

```
 if ($true)
        {

            break outer
            Write-Host OK
        }
```

I get the correct behavior.

```
retry 2
timestampServer http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
```

Long story short... do not use ':'

Comment: No, I have a function there, `WaitError`. This code was from a much greater script.