# PowerShell enter and delete unauthorized users

Tags: powershell

I am making a PowerShell script and I need help with making one part of my code. When I open my script I want my code to be like this

```
:start {
    $User = read-host 'Enter a user, If you are done, type done'
    $adminOrNormal = read-host 'a for admin or n for normal'
    if ($user -eq 'done') {
        Turn account type or delete incorrect users
    } else {
        goto start
    }
}
```

I know there are no goto and label functions in powershell, so I need a substitute for that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the start of a block, give this block a name (function) and call it.

How about this :

```
function Prompt-ForUser {

    $User = Read-Host 'Enter a user, If you are done, type done'

    switch($User) {

        'done'  { 'we are done here' }
        default {
            $adminOrNormal = Read-Host 'a for admin or n for normal'

            switch($adminOrNormal) {

                'a' { 'admin user' }
                'n' { 'normal user' }
                default { Prompt-ForUser }   

            }
        }

    }
}
Prompt-ForUser
```

FYI there *are* labels in PowerShell, but they are used to `Break` loops afaik. See the first answer to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043990/powershell-break-nested-loops) for example